# Difference between malloc and realloc?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I've two code samples for creating a integer array of 10 elements:

```
int *pi = (int*)0; 
realloc(pi,10);
```

and the other is the one that is written normally, i.e.:

```
int *pi;
pi= malloc(10*sizeof(int));
```

Now, my question is: The first type of assignment is legal but not used. Why, although there I may get the starting location of my choice?
Initialization of pointers with constants are legal but not used. Why?

Comment: You should not cast the return value of malloc in C.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When `NULL` is passed, `realloc` is equivalent to `malloc`.  The `NULL` call can be useful if you're re allocating in some kind of loop and don't want to have a special case the first time you allocate.

---

While we're at it, the fairly standard ways to use malloc and realloc are:

```
int* p;
p = malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); //Note that there's no cast
//(also, it could just be int* p = malloc(...);)

int* np = realloc(p, 15 * sizeof(int));
//Note that you keep the old pointer -- this is in case the realloc fails
```

---

As a tangential aside: history is the main reason you see declarations and assignments on different lines.  In older versions of C, declarations had to come first in functions.  That meant that even if your function didn't use a variable until 20 lines in, you had to declare at the top.

Since you typically don't know what the value of a variable not used for another 20 lines should be, you can't always initialize it to anything meaningful, and thus you're left with a declaration and no assignment at the top of your function.

In C99/C11, you do not have to declare variables at the top of scopes.  In fact, it's generally suggested to define variables as close to their use as possible.

Comment: Or `NULL`. It's legal in so far as the compiler doesn't throw a compilation error.

Comment: But in virtual memory environment my program owns the whole memory

Comment: @me.deeiip no, that is a false assumption. You cannot just use arbitrary memory addresses, the addresses you use must be granted to you by other functions that ensure the system knows how to allow you to use them.

Comment: Note that `NULL` is a null pointer but not all null pointers value are  `NULL`.

Comment: but in gcc the the initializing pointer with constant value(with casting) working normally (in ubuntu 11). But is failing in windows with vc++ compilers.

Comment: @me.deeiip That's because you've entered into the world of undefined behavior.  One of the behaviors possible in undefined behavior is 'correct' behavior, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @ouah Updated to reflect that :)

Comment: @me.deeiip: the behavior is *undefined*; it may *appear* to be working normally, but that's by accident, not design.  The first argument to `realloc` must either be NULL or the result of one of the `*alloc` functions.

Answer (score 11):

C requires that the pointer passed to `realloc` must be a pointer obtained from `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` function call (or a null pointer).

Comment: or `calloc` or a prior `realloc`, perhaps others?

Comment: @mah from the `alloc` family of fuctions might be the best way to express it.

Comment: @dmckee An over-cautious commenter might have added “[a pointer obtained] from the alloc family of functions that has not already been freed”, but that would be redundant: freeing any version of a pointer renders all its copies indeterminate. The other copies, in a sense, no longer exist and thus cannot be passed to `realloc()`, or `free()`. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/01/05/Double-free

Comment: *::staggers around melodramatically clutching heart::* Oh, woe is me! Out pendanted! Again! *::falls to the floor, sings aria, dies at great length::* @PascalCuoq You win.

Comment: To be very precise, `alloca()` must be excluded, as this does not allocate from the heap.

Answer (score 5):

The first assignment is *not* legal, because the pointer you pass into `realloc()` must have previously been given to you through an allocation of some kind. (Furthermore, you're ignoring its return value, something you must never do with allocations!)

`malloc()` is to create a buffer for something, of some fixed size. `realloc()` is to give back one buffer and get another of some (presumably) different size -- and it might give you back the same buffer you were using.